Modules missing from "Available updates"
When updating modules (Reports > Available updates) I noticed some of my modules were missing. Upon further investigation i noticed my module info.yml files were missing code
what I currently have: token.info.yml

what it should look like: token.info.yml

composer.json

Extend/Modules (version missing)

What would cause the code on lines 6 - 9 to be stripped?
Editor: VSCode
OS: Mac Sonoma

In this post you must show the section of composer.json that includes the token module. I've answered the most likely reason.

Hey @monalisa are you looking for the line of code like "drupal/token": "^1.11.0" in composer.json? This also happened to a bunch of other modules like entity embed and simple XML sitemap to name a few.
In the composer.json i can see the missing modules so they are there but they aren't displaying in the reports update page and under extend when i search for the modules i see them but their version number is missing.

We need to see your composer.json and we need to know what happens when you run composer install or composer update.

composer show drupal/token will be interesting too.

I ran composer create-project drupal/recommended-project my_site_name; cd my_site_name; composer require drupal/token:"^1.11.0". When I checked the token.info.yml file those lines were present. The question should contain more information about how Drupal and the Token module have been installed. The composer.json file does not say much, without knowing which commands have been executed.

Update, so it would seem when I run lando composer update --with-all-dependencies thats when the packing script information was stripped from the token module yml file.
So I think i'm on the right track but not sure if it's due to lando.

The most likely reason is that you installed them from Git checkouts rather than from ordinary version constraints, so drupal.org's packaging system didn't act on them.

This has kinda got to be the right answer, the fun part might be tracking down how it happened (custom repositories entry?). I also remember being in a similar position a while back, and even after correcting the module source in Composer, Drupal still wouldn't pick it up with drush cr - it needed an explicit call of drupal_flush_all_caches() or something like that. Might not still be an issue
